# A (local) Isometry from plane to upper half-plane

Tags: calculus, surfaces

What is a "simple" (local) isometry $F: P \rightarrow P_{+}$ where 
$$
P = \{(x,y,0) : x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}
$$
and 
$$
P_{+} \{(x,y,0) : x,y \in \mathbb{R} \mbox{ with } y>0\}.
$$
Here, *local isometry* $F: M \rightarrow N$ of surfaces is a mapping that
preserves dot products of tangent vectors.

I have tried with maps by involucring functions like the exponential function, but have not been successful in achieving a such isometry or local isometry. In fact, I am trying to solve the following exercise:

*Find two surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$ such that $S_1$ is locally isometric to $S_ 2$ but $S_2$ is not locally isometric to $S_1$*

Thanks in advance by any help

Comment: What is the purpose of the third coordinate?